# Multi platform script perl or awk

Tags: regex, perl, awk, backslash, eol

I am trying to match records in following format:

```
(-,username,domain1.co.uk)\
(-,username,domain2.co.uk)
```

either awk or perl must be used. I am using cygwin and wrote following code which works and matches both above entries:

```
awk 'BEGIN {musr="(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)"} {if ($0~musr) print $0}' netgroup
```

But if I try to modify this regexp to be more specific the output is nothing:

1st: match record then last backslash and then match newline:

```
"(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)\\$"
```

2nd: match new line immediatelly after record without backslash:

```
"(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)$"
```

So I decided to rewrite script into perl, hoping that perl can deal with backslashes and end of line symbols. For this purpose I used a2p this way:

```
echo  'BEGIN {musr="(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)"} {if ($0~musr) print $0}' | a2p.exe 
#!/usr/bin/perl
eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
    if $running_under_some_shell;
                        # this emulates #! processing on NIH machines.
                        # (remove #! line above if indigestible)

eval '$'.$1.'$2;' while $ARGV[0] =~ /^([A-Za-z_0-9]+=)(.*)/ && shift;
                        # process any FOO=bar switches

$, = ' ';               # set output field separator
$\ = "\n";              # set output record separator

$musr = '(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)';

while (<>) {
    chomp;      # strip record separator
    if ($_ =~ $musr) {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

This generated perl script also matches both entries, however if I try modify this script to more specific I get the following errors:

1st:

```
$musr = "(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)\\";
Trailing \ in regex m/(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)\/ at perlmatch.pl line 18, <> line 1.
```

2nd:

```
$musr = "(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)$";
Final $ should be \$ or $name at perlmatch.pl line 14, within string
syntax error at perlmatch.pl line 14, near "= "(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)$""
Execution of perlmatch.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

3rd:

```
$musr = "(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)\$";
[the output is nothing]
```

What I am doing wrong ? My question is also pointing to fact that if somebody needs to use script on several platforms (aix, solaris, linux) than using perl should be better approach that dealing with (non)GNU utils and various (g|n)awk versions etc. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems arise from string quoting in Perl.

`$musr = "(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)\\";` replaces `\\` with a single backslash when the string is created.  But you would need to pass two backslashes to the regex.  So you would have to put four in when you create the string.

`$musr = "(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)$";` tries to perform variable interpolation within the string.

In addition, parentheses should be escaped, as John Kugelman noted.

The solution is to use Perl's built-in delimiters for regular expressions, rather than normal quoted strings.  The simple way is to put it right into your loop:

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;      # strip record separator
    if ($_ =~ /\(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk\)$/) {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

If you do need to put the pattern into a variable first, use the special [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) 
operator.

```
my $musr = qr/\(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk\)$/;
while (<>) {
    chomp;      # strip record separator
    if ($_ =~ $musr) {
        print $_;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you qr operator was the thing I was looking for.

Comment: Of course also escaping the parentheses. One more question why there should be qr and simply quoting the regexp is not enought ? Regards

Comment: @Wakan Tanka, regular expressions use a special syntax in which certain characters and certain escape codes have a special meaning.  Therefore, Perl gives you the special `qr//` operator to handle this well.  If you had to put it in a regular string, you would need to have two layers of escaping: one for the string, then another one for the regex.  This creates a mess that is hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk)\\$
```

The problem here is not with the backslash at the end of the line, it's the parentheses. Parentheses are used for grouping. You need to escape them to match literal `(` `)` characters. You should also escape the dots so they match literal dots instead of "any character".

```
$ awk '/\(-,username,[^)]+\.co\.uk\)$/   {print}' netgroup 
(-,username,domain2.co.uk)
$ awk '/\(-,username,[^)]+\.co\.uk\)\\$/ {print}' netgroup 
(-,username,domain1.co.uk)\
```

If you stick with plain awk and don't use [gn]awk-specific features awk is very portable. More portable than perl is, I would think.

Comment: Both Awk and Perl are available on any major platform.  I don't think one is "more portable" than the other in general.  It depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: What do you mean stick with plain awk ? Sometimes I need to write scripts among several platforms (AIX, Solaris, HP-UX, Linux, Cygwin) and my experience is that "classic" linux commands (awk, sed) behaves slightly different in all *UNIXes. Eg. sed in Solaris cannot simpl replace the any character by newline like linux does. (sed 's/char/\n/') etc. I am just the perl newbie but so far when I write perl code it was running on all platforms with no problems unlike [gn]awk sed etc. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses must be escaped. Otherwise they group expressions. To be more specific, match an optional backslash at the end of the line (Backslashes are doubled because as string they must be escaped too).

```
awk 'BEGIN {musr="\\(-,username,[^)]+.co.uk\\)\\\\?$"} {if ($0~musr) print $0}' netgroup
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, those escaping of already escaped driving me crazy, can you post some good resources ?

Comment: @WakanTanka : use square brackets to escape then to avoid the nonstop `\\\\\\\…..` chaos. other than `"\^"` and `"\\"` where backslash is unavoidable, i always escape the rest of all `ASCII` punctuations via things like `[][]` , `[/]` , `[<?>(*){+}]`

Comment: @WakanTanka : so in your example, the cleaner escaping would be like :::::::::::::::::::::::::: :::::::::::::::: `musr = "[(]-,username,[^)]+[.]co[.]uk[)][\\\\]?$"`